# Android Studio build fails, but succeeds in console

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-ndk

I'm trying to build this project:

https://github.com/walleth/walleth

when I build it in my console it succeeds, like so:

[image]

but for some reason when I try to build it in Android Studio it fails with the following error:

[image]

Maybe it's because in my `~/.zshrc` I set the following variables:

```
Update your environment variables:

export ANT_HOME=/usr/local/opt/ant
export MAVEN_HOME=/usr/local/opt/maven
export GRADLE_HOME=/usr/local/opt/gradle
export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/opt/android-sdk
export ANDROID_NDK_HOME=/usr/local/opt/android-ndk

Update your paths (bonus points to a better solution to the hardcoded build tools version):

export PATH=$ANT_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$MAVEN_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$GRADLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/19.1.0:$PATH
```

in accordance with [this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/patrickhammond/4ddbe49a67e5eb1b9c03), is that possible?

Why would it build on my console but not in Android Studio?